# Kendo Angular upload file with other JSON parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using KendoUI in our Angular application and we need to upload a file to backend with other details like username,description,uploadtypeid as shown in below figure
[image]

I have checked with available kendo upload feature available , but it accepts only file to upload .How can I make changes to below stackblitz so I can accommodate other request body parameters.

[kendo-upload](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/uploads/upload/file-processing/#toc-automatic-upload-of-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, a solution for this issue would be to handle the form yourself, rather than letting the control perform the file upload. You should start by setting `autoUpload` to false, to prevent the control from uploading the image immediately after the file(s) are selected. Then you can manually handle the `select` and also the `remove` events to get control of the files that the user is selecting, then build your own payload with the files and the rest of the fields:

```html
<kendo-upload
  [autoUpload]="false"
  (select)="handleFileSelected($event)"
  (remove)="handleFileRemoved($event)">
</kendo-upload>
```

In your `.ts` you should have a field to keep track of the files, and the handlers for the `select` and `remove` events:

```
private files: FileInfo[] = [];

handleFileSelected(event: SelectEvent) {
  const newFiles = event.files.filter(
    (f) => !this.files.find((existingFile) => existingFile.name == f.name)
  );
  this.files = [...this.files, ...newFiles];
}

handleFileRemoved(event: RemoveEvent) {
  this.files = this.files.filter((f) => event.files.indexOf(f) === -1);
}
```

From your screenshot, I can see you only need one file, so the handlers could become simpler:

```
private file: FileInfo;

handleFileSelected(event: SelectEvent) {
  this.file = event.files.slice().shift();
}

handleFileRemoved(event: RemoveEvent) {
  this.file = null;
}
```

Then you can pass the file to your save method in your service:

```
handleSave() {
  this.service.saveUpload(
    this.uploadTypeId,
    this.description,
    this.uploadedUserId,
    this.file?.rawFile
  ).subscribe(res => {
    console.log('successfully saved', res);
  }
}
```